# I am unable to use ggplot2 to produce any graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I try to plot anything using `ggplot2`, I fail to produce a graph. The output changes, and is inconsistent, but in place of a graph, I receive a blank, white image, or axis without data, or all of the data, axis, and labels smushed into the center of the graph.

When making a scatter plot, like this:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width)) + geom_point()
```

I get the following error message:

> Error in UseMethod("depth") : 
>     no applicable method for 'depth' applied to an object of class "NULL"

and a blank graph with labelled axes (note the range of errors above though).

This happens both when I use `ggplot` and when I use `qplot`.

Currently, I am using:
OSX 10.11.6
R: 3.3.2
XQuartz: 2.7.11
All of the above have been re-installed.

Comment: We don't really have enough information to help. Ideally you could produce a fully reproducible example, but at the very least the output from `str(data)` might be informative.

Comment: I have added the output you asked for. I am happy to provide any additional information I can. Is there a way for me to upload the data set? Then I could provide all of my code in full...

Comment: Based on what you've shared, I can't reproduce your problem at all. I think you'll need to provide a fully reproducible example.

Comment: I have added my full code set. I don't know how to upload data sets or graph images, but I would be happy to do so.

Comment: Try running `ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) + geom_point()` What happens? (it is unclear if your issue is your specific data set or more general; using a builtin dataset like `iris` will help to clarify that)

Comment: That was a great idea! I posted the code and outputs above - I got the result I expected: still no graph.

Comment: Yeah, I can't replicate this at all, which suggests that there is something else going on in your installation or R session that is messed up, or that you haven't mentioned. The fact that you're getting an S3 dispatch error only suggests to me that you have done something to your R session that is masking or altering data or functions in some very strange way.

Comment: I 100% agree with you. In a class of ~100 people, I'm the only one with this error. None of the TA's can figure it out. I have reinstalled R twice, and gotten the same results. I reinstalled OSX and Quartz to no avail.

Comment: One additional detail: sometimes, if I close R completely, and run all of the above code, a clean, pretty graph is produced. However, as soon as I run the code again (in the same session) or any other ggplot functions, I get the errors/problems.

Comment: I removed your custom code/data example to try to make this as broadly applicable as possible. However, given that I can't get the same to happen on my computer (and neither can most others) it is still difficult to isolate this down to what is happening.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. Do you know of any other places it might be better to ask? My pet hypothesis is that the problem exists somewhere between R and the graphics software Quartz- only problem is "plot" works just fine.

Thank you Mark and Joran for trying!

Comment: Ideally you would ask at a forum specifically for whatever is causing the issue ... but given that you can't ID that, I'm not sure where that would be. I believe that `depth` is from `grid` and that base graphics would not call it. So, the issue is likely somewhere between `ggplot2` and `grid` (with quartz being a plausible culprit). Making sure you had the most up to date version of `grid` could help, but a recent clean install should already have that.

Comment: This [thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2015-February/426234.html) suggests the issue is with the plot device itself. Have you tried running it in RStudio (if you aren't; or plain R if you are)?

Comment: I just downloaded RStudio, and,as best I can tell, everything works fine in RStudio.  
The problem appears to be isolated to plain R. However, I can just use RStudio moving forward... Thanks! I'm still quite curious though...

Comment: Should have posted the output from your `sessionInfo`

Answer (score 5):

Try to resize plot boundaries. I got the same error in Rstudio and was able to fix just by doing that.

Comment: Thank you very much! this was driving me mad!

Comment: Unfortunately `sessionInfo()` doesn't report the current screen resolution or how you have your 'plots' window sized in your Rstudio - but just increasing the size of the window alleviated the error and it to render without altering anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I ran 'dev.off()' in the console, which I also do when R refuses to display a plot but doesn't give me an error message I can decipher.